# How to create an reverse index to read data adf

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to made a folder that contains the data from the folder name,I made this doing the index of the name folder but I have two types of names files. I need one to solve this two, I thought about doing the reverse index but I don’t know how. Please help me

example: date=2003-09-10 so I’l create the folder with the year 2003, another folder with month 09 and day 10 inside of this folder the file of date=2003-09-10. To solve the problem I creat this: @concat(pipeline().parameters.target,substring(item().name,2,4),’/‘,substring(item().name,7,2),’/‘,substring(item().name,10,2)).
It worked for this type of name folder but I have another names folder looks like this : d=2003-06-11. I need something that solve this two problems so I thought about reverse the index only to get the data but I don’t know how.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

How about [splitting the initial value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#split) by '=' and taking the second item in that array?  This should be a string that will contain only your date.  Here's a simple example setting a variable inside a For Each loop:

```
@split(item(),'=')[1]
```

NB The array is zero-based so ordinal 1 here is the second item in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @[Damien O - MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22339715/damien-o-msft)'s answer, after getting date part of the name, instead of using substring on it, you can get the desired part(`month,year,day`) of the date using split with `-`.

Store the date part using the above expression in a string variable and use the below expression to get the desired folder structure.

```
@concat(<your parameter>,split(variables('date'),'-')[0],'/',split(variables('date'),'-')[1],'/',split(variables('date'),'-')[2])
```

[image]

Here, to show the output I have appended the result to an array and here is the result.

[image]

**NOTE:** Ignore the warning `Cannot fit unknown into the function parameter string list item` while using split in dynamic expression. It won't affect the pipeline run.